# Hadoop jar submission error java.lang.InstantiationException

Tags: hadoop, cassandra

I'm trying to run my jar on hadoop filesystem but getting this exception
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Esi.png)

[image: Exception stacktrace]

My code is running successfully if i run it from eclipse.

Here is my Runner main class

```
    public class ReadCassandra extends Configured implements Tool{

        public static void main(String args[]){
            try{
                /*ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(),new ReadCassandra(), args);
                System.exit(0);*/

                String keyspace ="Read_log";
                String clg ="readValidPost";
                String rowkey="117761667160131";
                List<ByteBuffer> cn = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();
                List<String> cl = new ArrayList<String>();
                cl.addAll(MyHector.getColumn(rowkey));
                for (String string : cl) {
                    ByteBuffer bf = ByteBufferUtil.bytes(string);
                    cn.add(bf);
                }
                Configuration conf = new Configuration();
                Job job = new Job(conf,"MEJfsd");
                //job.setJarByClass(ReadCassandra.class);

                job.setInputFormatClass(AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.class);
                job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

                job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
                job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

                job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
                job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);

                ConfigHelper.setInputRpcPort(job.getConfiguration(), "9160");
                ConfigHelper.setInputInitialAddress(job.getConfiguration(), "127.0.0.1");
                ConfigHelper.setInputPartitioner(job.getConfiguration(), "org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner");
                ConfigHelper.setInputColumnFamily(job.getConfiguration(), keyspace, clg);

                SlicePredicate predicate = new SlicePredicate().setColumn_names(cn);
                ConfigHelper.setInputSlicePredicate(job.getConfiguration(), predicate);

                FileSystem.get(job.getConfiguration()).delete(new Path("Output"), true);
                FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("Output"));
                job.waitForCompletion(true);

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {


            return (1);
        }


    }
```

I'm running using command

```
hadoop jar /home/winoria/Documents/JarFiles/ReadCas.jar ReadCassandra
```

Comment: Can u please provide complete error from beginning..

Comment: yeah sure... but its a very lengthy code... :(

Comment: How you are running it from the command line?

Comment: hadoop jar /home/winoria/Documents/JarFiles/ReadCas.jar ReadCassandra

Comment: Are you generating a Runnable jar from eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting your input format class to an abstract class:

```
 job.setInputFormatClass(AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.class);
```

You need to set it to something instantiate-able. But I don't know about Cassandra-Hadoop integration and what makes sense in your case. Just make sure that it is not an abstract class.

Comment: i agree dude... but its not working on doing like this.. same problem